# How to declare a singelton in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, singleton, mxgraph, ambient

I would like to integrate an existing library into my typescript project. There is a (external) singleton object which i want to declare and use.

Example:
Within xyz.js, following object will be declared:

```
var mxUtils = {
    /* some fancy code */
    findNode: function(node, attr, value)
    {
        // even more fancy code
        return node;
    }
};
```

During runtime, there is a global single instance of mxUtils. Since this is an external library, I don't want to implement or rewrite the whole library in typescript.

Now I tried to declare this singleton, but I failed.

I tried this code, to declare the Object as global var.

Utils.d.ts:

```
declare interface ImxUtils { 
    findNode(node:any, attr:string, value:string):any;
}

declare var mxUtils: ImxUtils;
```

My compiler is completely satisfied with this, but during runtime, mxUtils is undefined

main.ts:

```
// some fancy things
export class fancyComponent implements OnInit {
    // some magic here...
    var tmpNode = mxUtils.findNode(aNode, aString1, aString2);    
}
```

Even though my debugger lists a global mxUtils Object.

Can anyone help me on this?

Please remark: 
* xyz.js is already referenced and is present. 
e.g.

xyz.js

```
function mxEventObject(name)
{
//
}

mxEventObject.prototype.getName = function()
{
    return this.name;
};
```

Utils.d.ts

```
declare class mxEventObject {
    constructor(name: string);
    getName: () => string;
}
```

main.ts

```
export class fancyComponent implements OnInit {
    // some magic here...
    var tmpEvent = new mxEventObject(aSampleString);

}
```

will work as expected.

Since there is a global object named mxUtils, but i can not access this object within my export of fancyComponent, i suppose there is a scope problem.

Comment: Why would `mxUtils` not be undefined ? Where is it initialized ? the definitions in `.d.ts` are just deifnitions, they tell the compiler that that interface and more importantly the variable **exist** at runtime. Not the compiler's job how they come into existance.

Comment: are you using angular ?

Comment: you need to add xyz.js to scripts list in .angular-cli.json

Comment: This object *does* exist during runtime and is accessible at my javascript console during runtime,

Comment: I have test your code and it 's working https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g9sy1v check the console you said that you can access to mxUtils  object throw console this mean it 's been loaded if it s a js library

Answer (score 0):

In angular in better to relay on DI ( Dependency Injection) system to handle object creation and inject theses object to component , you need to create an angular service and add this service to providers list in AppModule component decorator.

*mx-utils.service.ts*

```
export class MxUtilsService {

  /* some fancy code */
  public findNode(node:any, attr:any, value:any) {
    // even more fancy code
    return node;
  }
}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [MxUtilsService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*app.compoennet.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MxUtilsService } from './mx-utils.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(private _mxUtilsService: MxUtilsService) {
    console.log(this._mxUtilsService);
    console.log(this._mxUtilsService.findNode({node:1},'node',1));
  }
}
```

> any service add to providers list in appModule(root) is considered a
>   singleton , MxUtilsService will create ones and will be the same object when you inject to another components

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dj8okw)

> Why your object is undefined you need to add `xyz.js` to scripts list
>   in `.angular-cli.json`

Comment: this is no helpful choice, since this is an external library, which will be updated frequently. That's why i wrote, i don't want to rewrite this xyz library.

Comment: have update the answer you need to include xyz.js to be bundle in runtime @Stefan